# When does spring batch close input streams?

Tags: spring-batch

This is in context of using spring batch 3.0.8. I created a job where some of the steps are reading from a csv file using the Spring FlatFileItemReader which is being wrapped by the MultiResourceItemReader. I would like to know if spring automatically closes the input stream after reading the file in or is that something I need to explicitly do? If I need to close it, then what are some recommendations on where to close it?

The reason I am asking this is because we noticed that the MultiResourceItemReader is not closing input streams when it finishes it's current step and going on to the next step which is a big problem for us because we are reading over a 1,000 files and will read more in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I would like to know if spring automatically closes the input stream after reading the file in or is that something I need to explicitly do?

Yes, Spring Batch will automatically close the resources once the step is finished. You don't need to call the `close` method as this is part of the lifecycle of the reader within a chunk oriented step.

Answer (score 0):

`MultiResourceItemReader` delegates and doesn't have a `close` method. The `delegate` has a close method. The delegate's `close` method is called when a `Resource` is finished with.

So; you may have to implement the `close` method on your delegate, or override, to call a `close` method on the current `resource` (on `close` call the `resource` is the one that is just finished with) if your implementation of `Resource` has a `close` method.

I don't think that's how `Resource` is intended to be used. I think it's intended to be more of a "supplier" of an `InputStream` or `File` or similar.

And thus, my personal favourite pattern, if you will, is that there is a field for the input stream which I assign in the `delegate` `open` method, and that asks the current `resource` for an `InputStream` and assigns, and then, in the `close` method, I call `close` on the input stream which I have assigned.

Spring Batch has no real way of knowing if your `InputStream` from a `Resource` needs to be closed, and when.

Some baked in implementations work this way, and some 3rd party libraries which provide readers. And all my readers.
To me, a `Resource` is a supplier which may (in some cases) be called repeatedly to provide either the same, or a new `InputStream` each time.

So; in your case with the `MultiResourceItemReader` class: you may have to close any input streams obtained in your delegate reader, in the `close` method of the delegate reader which is called from `MultiResourceItemReader` pre resource and once as a final method when Spring Batch calls `close` on the `MultiResourceItemReader` at the end of the Step